# A linear map to a finite-dimensional space is injective iff it's a section

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $W$ is finite-dimensional and $T∈L(V,W)$. Prove that $T$ is injective if and only if there exists $S∈L(W,V)$ such that $ST$ is the identity map on $V$.

I feel hard about the existence part of the proof, please help me, thanks.

Comment: That title sure was misleading...

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** First, figure out what $Sw$ needs to be if $w$ belongs to the image $\operatorname{im}T$ of $T$. Second, show that there is a subspace $Z$ of $W$ so that $W$ is the direct sum of $\operatorname{im}T$ and $Z$, and define $Sz=0$ for $z\in Z$.

(Note that $Z$ is not unique. The finite dimension of $W$ is strictly speaking not necessary for this, but an elementary proof of the existence of $Z$ will rely on it. Just start with a basis for $\operatorname{im}T$ and extend it to a basis for $W$.)